# Error in getGroupsFormula.default(correlation) : 'form' argument must be a formula

Tags: r, time-series, non-linear-regression

I need help with the R codes. I want to use gnls function to fit nonlinear regression with ARMA(1,1)
I post the codes with the error. Could you please help me to fix the error message?

```
  library(forecast)
  library(nlme)
  set.seed(54321)



   Error in getGroupsFormula.default(correlation) : 
   'form' argument must be a formula
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the ultimate aim. You've provided code but it's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am using simulated data. My model is about nonlinear regression with autoregressive errors. By using gnls fuction we could get the estimated parameters for both regression and autoregressive